# Constraints for iPhone 6+

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8, xcode6, size-classes

I have three buttons on a screen and I am adding them to the bottom half of the screen. I am using size classes and want them same on all iPhone portrait orientations. I am adding constraints separately for Compact Width | Regular height and Compact Width | Any Height. But for one resolution the UI is not setted right and thats either iPhone 6+ or iPhone 4s. Anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong and how to design for all iPhone resolutions using size classes. It appears I have arrived at a deadlock.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are using size classes so have to set vertical and horizontal spacing. In Universal Storyboard there  are option "Any Width Any height" and "add new alignment constraints"

See this link.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G53PuA_TlXk

Comment: This Video was quite helpful but I have done these with hit and trial method. What I want to know is that is there any way I can specify constraints separately for iPhone 6+ ? I am trying to do that by adding separately for wC|hR and wC|hAny. But only one of them works either wC|hR or wC|hAny.

Comment: When I change to wc|hAny from the bottom bar it says Base Values for all compact width layouts. And when I do wC|hR it says Final Values for all iPhones in portrait. I am confused by these Base values and Final values. What is the difference and am facing issues because of this?